# PDF software to read many documents side-by-side in iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, pdf

*This thread is a part of the major thread about using iPad for education purposes [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74399/how-to-read-and-write-with-ipad-ipad-for-studying-required-styluses-and-apps).*

When I do my homework, I often need to recap lecture notes and at the same time do assignments. Before my printer broke, I printed everything -- now with my iPad, I use only the screen. The problem is that I have only one iPad and so I am looking for a software using which I could read many PDFs at the same time. Does such a PDF reader exist?

I have used PDF Expert but it lacks this feature. I have also tried apps such as iAnnotate but cannot find this feature.

Answer (score 2):

[Side by Side](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/side-by-side-dropbox-support/id386528623?mt=8) allows you to read up to 4 different PDFs side by side on an iPad.

Comment: Wow but how can I get my material from DropBox to it? Anyway +1, this is getting to it :)

Comment: Well, this was not part of your original question, right? However, press the circle in the upper left corner of a window, press the info button, and you will find an option to link your Dropbox there.

Comment: Yes but it is only uploading files from the app, not allowing me to download my school material from DropBox.

Comment: Visit Dropbox and move/copy your school material inside the SideBySide folder. In the app, sync with your Dropbox and files from the SideBySide folder will become available in the App.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Easy Annotate](http://www.easy-annotate.com), it allows showing and annotating two PDFs next to each other.

According to the website" "The only app that can annotate PDFs side-by-side"

They have a dropbox option which I use myself.

Answer (score 0):

iRead PDF.

Alternatively you can just email them to yourself and open them up in Safari or whatever web browser you use. I'm not aware of any way to have view of multiple PDFs at once but you can only read one thing at a time anyway so I think most people think tabs is sufficient.

Comment: ...sorry? Can I view multiple pdfs at once in iRead PDF or not? I do nothing with more PDF readers, I have bought all popular ones such as PDF Expert, iAnnotate -- but they miss the feature of many documents at once view.

Answer (score 0):

Try Foxt PDF. It can open 5 documents in 5 tabs at a time. However it seems the resolution is slightly poorer than Adobe Acrobat. If it's a matter of settings then I haven't gotten the trick. That's why I still use Adobe for single document viewing. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same thing .what i used to do is open in two apps and read ..rather difficult . But if you try GoodNotes then there is an option to do it. You can also open a note in another tab and copy important things there . Hope you find this helpful

Answer (score -1):

try ezPDF, can open 2 pdf in split screen